# Foundation CSS Framework namespace

Tags: css, namespaces, sass, wordpress

How can I use foundation `CSS` framework only for one div?
I want to load the foundation to `wp-admin`. After loading the `wp-admin` I have problems with tabs, menu etc. Then I want to make container / namespace for foundation.

```
.foundation{
    // Here foundation styles, how to load?
}
```

Anyone have ideas for this? Or alternatives?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Anything at all?

Comment: yes, i tried but its my sass compiller error, after change all works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sass:

```
.foundation {
    @import 'path/to/foundation.css'
}
```

This will nest all of the foundation styles in the `.foundation` class.